# How to set change tracking on a Visual Studio database project (SSDT)

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-data-tools, change-tracking

I have a SQL Server 2005 DB project and am looking to deploy the Schema over an existing DB that is on a later version of SQL Server. The issue I have is that Change Tracking is enabled on the DB I wish to deploy to and so the first thing SSDT wants to do is disable CT. This poses a problem as I get the error below:

> (43,1): SQL72014: .Net SqlClient Data Provider: Msg 22115, Level 16,
> State 1, Line 5 Change tracking is enabled for one or more tables in
> database 'Test'. Disable change tracking on each table before
> disabling it for the database. Use the sys.change_tracking_tables
> catalog view to obtain a list of tables for which change tracking is
> enabled. (39,0): SQL72045: Script execution error.  The executed
> script:
>
> ```
> IF EXISTS (SELECT 1
>        FROM   [master].[dbo].[sysdatabases]
>        WHERE  [name] = N'$(DatabaseName)')
> BEGIN
>     ALTER DATABASE [$(DatabaseName)]
>         SET CHANGE_TRACKING = OFF 
>         WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE;
> END
> ```

In an effort to get around this I have created a PreDeployment script that executes the below:

```
/* Run pre-deployment scripts to resolve issues */
IF(SELECT SUBSTRING(@@VERSION, 29,4)) = '11.0'

BEGIN

PRINT 'Enabling Change Tracking';

DECLARE @dbname VARCHAR(250)
SELECT @dbname = DB_NAME()

EXEC('
        IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM [master].[dbo].[sysdatabases] WHERE name = ''' + @dbname + ''')
        
        ALTER DATABASE ['+ @dbname +
        ']SET CHANGE_TRACKING = ON
        (CHANGE_RETENTION = 5 DAYS, AUTO_CLEANUP = ON);
');

EXEC('
IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM sys.change_tracking_tables ctt
          INNER JOIN sys.tables t ON t.object_id = ctt.object_id
          INNER JOIN sys.schemas s ON s.schema_id = t.schema_id
          WHERE t.name = ''TableName'')
BEGIN
    ALTER TABLE [dbo].[TableName] ENABLE CHANGE_TRACKING;
END;');
```

So based on the DB Version Change Tracking is set to enabled on the DB and relevant Tables assuming it is not already enabled.I got this idea from a previous post: [# ifdef type conditional compilation in T-SQL sql server 2008 2005](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6612224/ifdef-type-conditional-compilation-in-t-sql-sql-server-2008-2005)

Unfortunately this is still not working as SSDT is trying to disable Change Tracking before the PreDeployment script is executed.

Answer (score 7):

Make sure change tracking is enabled in your database project.

Open your database project's properties > Project Settings > Database Settings... > Operational tab > check the "Change tracking" option

Comment: Yeah that would be the simple solution but as the project is 2005 this option is not listed. Ideally I would switch the project to 2012 and carry out your suggestion. Unfortunately the project needs to stay 2005 for the foreseeable.

Answer (score 2):

As Keith said if you want it in enable it. If you do want to disable it then just run your script before doing the compare so you have a pre-pre-deploy script like:

https://the.agilesql.club/Blog/Ed-Elliott/Pre-Compare-and-Pre-Deploy-Scripts-In-SSDT

If you are disabling it then it is a one off thing so pretty simple.

Other options are to write your own deployment contributor and raising a bug via connect.

Deployment Contributor:

https://the.agilesql.club/blog/Ed-Elliott/2015/09/23/Inside-A-SSDT-Deployment-Contributor

https://github.com/DacFxDeploymentContributors/Contributors

Ed

Comment: This looks a useful read and sounds similar to what I have started to try using through Octopus PreDeployment scripts. That said having this earlier in the CI pipeline would make life easier not to mention safer so I will take a look at the post in more detail and try to replicate.